# Assume $G$ is abelian. Prove that $p$ divides $|Z(G)|$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $p$ be a positive prime number. Suppose $|G| = p^
n$. for some positive integer $n$.

I know to be abelian you have to be commutative, where $ab=ba$ and $a,b \in$ a group. And we have that the center:  $Z(G) = \{z ∈ G : ∀g \in G, zg = gz\}$. Its looks so easy to connect but I am not sure how to connect.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian $Z(G)=G$....

Comment: Hmmm that simple huh.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Melech

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $G$ is abelian, $G=Z(G)$, so it's obvious.

But I want to tell you that even if $G$ is not abelian the theorem also holds.
It follows from the Class Equation.

Comment: +1 Indeed $|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{j=1}^{r}[G:C(g_j)]$ for $g_j$ representatives in the conjugacy classes outside the center shows for any finite $p$-group, the center cannot be trivial